# Get array from node.js (server-side)to react app.js (client-side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, client-side

I'm trying to get an array from `node.js` (server-side) to react `app.js` (client-side)
so I need to get files to array from node and send it to `app.js` it seems like `module.exports` from node and import from `app.js` does not work like this here is what I tried

`node.js` file:

```
const fs= require('fs');
const files=fs.readdirSync('../Movies');
module.exports={
  movies:files
}
```

`app.js` file

```
import { movies } from "./server/server.js";
console.log(movies);
```

do have have to

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.
`app.js` in client, It can't import `"./server/server.js"`
But you can send array has name of file in that forder when render.

`node.js`:

```
const files=fs.readdirSync('../Movies');
// when user request your page (this example use ejs)
res.render('<your_ejs_file>', {
    myFiles: files,
});
// in your_ejs_file, create variable:
<script>
    var yourFiles = <%= JSON.stringify(myFiles)%>            
</script>
```

`yourFiles` is array named of file in `your_folder`
If you want load file from server, you can use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to load it.

I use name of variable diffrent to you avoid mistake them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from server-side to the client-side, you can use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) (sending HTTP requests to the server using front-end JavaScript). There are also other useful packages that you can use to simplify your work, like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: can you give me an example for how to send the array i have above in my question to client-side using ajax